# mysql query to display everything from a table but not a certain word

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table called movie and in that a field called title. I select everything using;

```
<?php
$query = "SELECT * FROM movie"; 
$result = @mysql_query($query, $connection) 
or die ("Unable to perform query<br>$query");
?>
```

Then I echo out the title using a loop;

```
<?php while($row= mysql_fetch_array($result)) { ?>  
<b>Item Seen: </b><?php echo $row['title'] ?><br>
<hr width="auto" size=1 color="#e1e1e1">
<?php } ?>
```

Allot of films have 'the' in the title which is causing issues when sorting alphabetically.
Therefore is there a way to show the film titles but if they contain 'the' in the title. To ignore that and just display the rest of the title?

For example if the movie title was 'the day after tommorow' but what was displayed was simply 'day after tomorrow'.

Obviously you can manually remove them from the DB but they still need to contain the 'the' in the backend for other functionality on the site?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about (EDIT as per comment):

```
SELECT REPLACE (m.title, 'The', '') movietitlefordisplay, m.* FROM movie m
```

Comment: Hello thanks for this, how do you still select everything from the movie table so you can display all the data from the table still. As using the above query the rest of the data in the other fields in the movie table stops displaying. Can you add the * in there somewhere?

Comment: see my EDIT above... you can just list the columns you need separated with a comma or use the above modified statement... please don't forget to upvote/mark as accepted any answer that was of help...

Comment: Hello Yahia this doesn't work the 'the' is still showing on the title. I copied your exact EDIT above?

Comment: @MartinDye: Did you change your code to display the `movietitlefordisplay` column instead of the `title` column?

Comment: aha no was still trying to echo title, have corrected this all working. Thanks both.